# What is the point of GlobalMaterialLocalizations and flutter_localizations?

Tags: flutter

The [Flutter article for internationalization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#setting-up-an-internationalized-app-the-flutter_localizations-package) states the following:

> To add support for other languages, an application must specify additional MaterialApp properties, and include a separate package called `flutter_localizations`.

However, I do not understand what the point of `flutter_localizations` is and why I "**must [...] include**" it in my app if I want to add support for other languages.

If I take a look at [`GlobalMaterialLocalizations`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_localizations/GlobalMaterialLocalizations-class.html), which is what `flutter_localizations` apparently adds (along with the Widgets and Cupertino versions), I can only find a bunch of seemengly random strings I have never seen translated into a bunch of languages.
I have never seen these strings in my Flutter app.

Do I **really** need to include `flutter_localizations` if I want to internationalize my app, i.e. *are these strings used anywhere* by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually no.

It depends how you want to implement you internationalization.

#### You can get current local by:

```dart
/// Because of flutter issue
/// https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/38323
/// So return `locals[1]` instead of `window.locale`;
var locals = window.locales;
var local = (locals.length > 1) ? locals[1] : window.locale;
```

#### Benefit of current `flutter_localizations`

I think the benefit of this lib is that it also handle the text direction stuff in

#### The other way

If you only need to handle the Strings' translation, no need to handle text direction(`ltr(left to right)` or `rtl(right to left)`):

You handle your strings by the value returned above:

```
abstract class Strings {
  String hello;
  factory Strings() // => instance;
  {
    var locals = window.locales;
    var local = (locals.length > 1) ? locals[1] : window.locale;
    if (local != null) {
      // log('Strings.load(${local.languageCode})');

      if (local.languageCode == 'zh') {
        return _StringsZH.instance;
      }
    }
    return _StringsEN.instance;
  }
}

class _StringsEN implements Strings {
  String hello = 'Hello 2019';
  _StringsEN._();
  static _StringsEN instance = _StringsEN._();
}
class _StringsZH implements Strings {
  String hello = '你好 2019';
  _StringsZH._();
  static _StringsZH instance = _StringsZH._();
}
```

And use it like

```dart
Strings().hello;
```